# EWS with delegated authentication - not supported browser

Tags: oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

I am writing a .net application that uses EWS with delegated authentication. When I try to authenticate, automatically appears a window (not a browser) that asks for login (email, password and one time code).

After login phase (that is successfull) appears an error that says:

**UPDATE YOUR BROWSER**
Your browser is not supported or up-to-date. Try updating it or else download and install the latest version of Microsoft Edge.

Does anyone experienced the same issue?
Thanks!

The error should not appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what libraries, controls and version of .net it sounds like it's opening in IE which is the default behaviour for older/legacy code. Best practice is to use the MSAL library for authentication which has some options to control the browser that is used see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-web-browsers